# Showing Org-Mode Table Plots as Images on Export?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to make gnuplot plots from tables as per:

```
#+PLOT: title:"Grades in Physics and Mathematics" ind:2 deps:(3 4) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]" set:"xlabel 'Student'" set:"ylabel 'grades'"
|---+--------+-------------+---------|
|   | Grades | Mathematics | Physics |
|---+--------+-------------+---------|
| # | Ben    |         9.2 |     9.9 |
| # | Tom    |         6.7 |     7.7 |
| # | Tim    |         7.5 |     6.7 |
| # | Dean   |         8.0 |     7.0 |
```

...automatically show the image of the plot when you export to HTML?

Comment: There is a file option with which you can output the graph to a file [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-plot.html). I could not make it work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative option would be

```
#+Name: mytable
|---+--------+-------------+---------|
|   | Grades | Mathematics | Physics |
|---+--------+-------------+---------|
| # | Ben    |         9.2 |     9.9 |
| # | Tom    |         6.7 |     7.7 |
| # | Tim    |         7.5 |     6.7 |
| # | Dean   |         8.0 |     7.0 |

#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :var  data=mytable :file output.png :export results
set title "Grades in Physics and Mathematics"
set style data histogram
set xlabel "Student"
set ylabel "Grades"
set auto x
plot data using 2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col
#+END_SRC
```